# 500 Server error on google oauth call

Tags: php, oauth

I am making a backend auth system to my google login, that will validate the token, extract the relevant data and create a new user or check a current one as shown here:

```
// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
if(isset($_GET['id_token']) && !(empty($_GET['id_token']))) {
    $id_token = $_GET['id_token'];
    $CLIENT_ID ='client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    echo "1\n";
    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
    echo "2\n";
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    //$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    echo "3\n";
    if ($payload) {
        $result = array(
            "id" => $payload['sub'],
            "email" => $payload['email'],
            "name" => $payload['name'],
            "source" => $payload['iss'],
            "picture" => $payload['picture'],
        );
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM oauth_users WHERE id='".$payload['sub']."'");
        if (!$query) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); }
        if(!(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO oauth_users (id, email, name, source, picture) VALUES ('" . $payload['sub'] . "', '" . $payload['email'] . "','" . $payload['name'] . "', '" . $payload['iss'] . "', '" . $payload['picture'] . "')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
        echo "[" . json_encode($result) . "]";
    } else {
        echo "Error: failed to validate";
    }
}
```

This code worked on locally, I hosted it on my server and tried to run it but get a 500 internal server error every time it reaches this line:
`$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);`

This code, the barebones version atleast was copied directly from googles oauth PHP documentation so I am not sure what is faiing. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

(It will echo '1..2..500 interal error')

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Perhaps the shorthand array notation is breaking because using < 5.4, that should be a fatal error though and no output would be thrown.

Comment: try to change `$_GET['id_token'];` to  `$_POST['id_token'];`

Comment: ive tried post with same results @B.Desai Nothing in an error log and I believe the server is running >= 5.4